# OpenCL Deployment

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I am considering writing an nbody style simulation in c/c++ that needs to run on most personal computers. Essentially an O(n^2) particle simulator.

Because this needs to be rather user friendly I was hoping to have 1 Windows exe file that wouldn't require the user to install anything. Is this possible with OpenCL? Does anybody know how to do this without writing two seperate codes?

Comment: Thanks, I think I will need to write a inclusive GPU checker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user would always need to have the latest version of the driver for their video card installed. AMD users would also need the AMD APP SDK. I guess you could make an installer that determines the users video card and downloads the correct drivers for them, but I don't think you can do this without any installing.
That would require loading the drivers from your program. I'm not sure whether that is possible, and even if it's possible, you would essentially have to write your own driver, which is a lot of work.

So in short, no.